Issue with clicking Google Ads "Click to Continue" button in Appium + Python
I am currently automating an app using Appium and Python for app automation. Recently, Google ads have started appearing randomly within the app. These ads contain a "Click to Continue" button, which I need to interact with programmatically. However, I am facing challenges in clicking this button using Appium.
I'm having trouble locating the "Click to Continue" button element for Google ads while inspecting with Appium. It seems that the entire ad page is contained within a single element. As I'm new to Appium, I apologize if my terminology isn't precise.
I have tried using coordinate-based clicking, but it is not proving to be consistent across different devices and screen resolutions.
Could anyone suggest a more robust method or approach to interact with such ads using Appium and Python? Any insights or examples of how others have tackled similar challenges would be greatly appreciated.
Please refer to this image
